# Making a Cloud Storage bucket accessible only by a certain service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have an storage bucket that I created on GCP. I created the bucket following the instructions described here (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets). Additionally, I created it using uniform bucket-level access control.

However, I want the objects in the bucket to be accessible by instances running under a certain service account. Although, I do not see how to do that. In the permissions settings, I do not see how I can specify a service account for read-write access.

Comment: You mean Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket right? S3 is AWS specific name.

Comment: @MR.K Ah yes :) Sorry, new to this.

Comment: You can see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58818696/4539626

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a service account, run the following command in Cloud Shell:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create storage-sa --display-name "storage service account"
```

You can grant roles to a service account so that the service account can perform specific actions on the resources in your GCP project. For example, you might grant the storage.admin role to a service account so that it has control over objects and buckets in Google Cloud Storage.

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <Your Project ID> --member <Service Account ID> --role <Role You want to Grant>
```

Once role is granted you can select this service account while creating the instance.

Alternatively, to do this via Google Cloud Console see [Creating and enabling service accounts for instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have created your service account, you can then change/set the access control list (ACL) permissions on your bucket or objects using ths gsutil command.

Specifically:

```
gsutil acl set [-f] [-r] [-a] file-or-canned_acl_name url...
gsutil acl get url
gsutil acl ch [-f] [-r] <grant>... url...

where each <grant> is one of the following forms:

  -u <id|email>:<perm>
  -g <id|email|domain|All|AllAuth>:<perm>
  -p <viewers|editors|owners>-<project number>:<perm>
  -d <id|email|domain|All|AllAuth|<viewers|editors|owners>-<project number>>:<perm>
```

Please review the following article for more depth and description:

- [acl - Get, set, or change bucket and/or object ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl)

You can also set/change acls through the Cloud Console web interface and through GCS API.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to create a service account [Creating a new service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances).
2. Set up a new instance to run as a service account [Set instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using).
3. In the Google Cloud Console go to Storage/bucket/right_corner dots/Edit bucket permissions

Add Member/servive account/

Role/Storage Admin